# Is there an equivalent for the French "Bonaldi effect" in English?

Tags: vocabulary, french

In France, we designate by "Bonaldi effect" a particular case of the Murphy's law which states that:

> Any demonstration of any product that worked perfectly at the rehearsals will fail miserably during the public demonstration.

It takes its name from Jérôme Bonaldi, a television host who encountered many problems when he presented unusual objects and inventions.

How would you describe such a syndrome in English?

Comment: It seems to be [correctly attributed](http://weirdthingshappenalltime.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/some-of-murphys-law-strange.html) (if rarely mentioned) in English also.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That article you linked to was quite entertaining.

Comment: The exact term in French is *L'effet Bobaldi* (sometimes *syndrome Bonaldi*). Discussed on this thread on *Linguaphiles*: ["Corollary on Murphy's Law"](http://linguaphiles.livejournal.com/4797193.html), referred to by s.o. as the  "demo effect".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=demo%20effect) suggests an appropriate term: **demo effect**.

Its downside term is that is typically connected with high-tech, and it has other meanings.

From another [source](https://weirdthingshappenalltime.blogspot.ae/2007/05/some-of-murphys-law-strange.html):

> Similar to [the bonaldi effect], the **demo effect**: an object, software, etc., used daily with no incident, would present a dysfunction during a demonstration, especially in public. exemple [sic] : bill gates' presentations of different windows, ending with a famous error on a blue screen.